# Como acceder desde otra clase a una lista "private static List<T>"?

Tags: c#, lista

Tengo este codigo:

```
public static class GenDAO<T> where T : IEntidad // antes static
{
    private static List<T> BDenMemoria = new List<T>();
    private static int NextId = 1;

    public static int Crear(T entidad)
    {
        entidad.id = NextId++;
        BDenMemoria.Add(entidad);
        return entidad.id;
    }

    public static T Buscar(int id)
    {
        return BDenMemoria.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == id);
    }

    public static void Actualizar(T entidad)
    {
        int indice = BDenMemoria.FindIndex(x => x.id == entidad.id);
        if (indice != -1)
            BDenMemoria[indice] = entidad;
    }

    public static void Eliminar(int id)
    {
        int indice = BDenMemoria.FindIndex(x => x.id == id);
        if (indice != -1)
            BDenMemoria.RemoveAt(indice);
    }
}
```

Es parte de una código para windows forms y necesito acceder desde la clase principal a la lista BDenMemoria que es private y static, para mostrar en un DataGridView los objetos que posee la lista. Pero no se como acceder a esa lista desde fuera.
Gracias!

Comment: Respuesta corta: no puedes (para eso está marcada como private). Es posible que mediante Reflection pudieras acceder, pero no es recomendable. Aqui la base es...por qué quieres acceder a una lista privada desde fuera? Esa clase tiene métodos para el acceso a la lista, y es lo que debes usar.

Comment: Gracias! Y como podría mostrar en un DatagridView en la clase principal  los elementos de esa lista?

Comment: Como ya te han dicho, para poder hacerlo deberías modificar la clase para crear un método o propiedad que fuera publica que devolviera la lista que ahora tienes como privada.

Answer (score 0):

En el ejemplo que has puesto, la Lista **BDenMemoria** es de tipo **static**.

La siguiente definición aparece en la [documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members) de Microsoft:

*El miembro estático es invocable en una clase, incluso si no se ha creado ninguna instancia de la clase. Siempre se tiene acceso al miembro estático con el nombre de clase, no con el nombre de instancia. Solo existe una copia de un miembro estático, independientemente del número de instancias de la clase que se creen.*

Por lo que el acceso a la Lista se realiza directamente sin instanciar la clase.

```
GenDAO.BDenMemoria;
```

Si no puedes cambiar el modificador de acceso **private**, puedes añadir un método que haga de **wrapper**.

Comment: Gracias! pero en teoría tengo que dejar esa clase tal y como está, sin modificación alguna

Comment: Utilizar la clase *public static T Buscar(int id)* dentro de un bucle y saca el contenido de la lista.

Answer (score 0):

Un miembro `private` sólo es accesible a través de miembro de la misma clase [como se explica en la documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/private):

> El acceso privado es el nivel de acceso menos permisivo. Los miembros privados solo son accesibles dentro del cuerpo de la clase o el struct en el que se declaran.

La única manera de acceder directamente a la lista sería con *por lo menos* estas dos características:

1. La clase **no** es estática.
2. El modificador de acceso de la lista es [`protected`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/protected).

Una manera *indirecta* de obtener la lista sería a través de una iteración con el método `Buscar`:

```
IList<IEntidad> BDenMemoria = new List<ClaseEntidad>();
int i = 0;
bool stop = false;
do
{
    IEntidad obj = GenDAO.Buscar(i);
    if (EqualityComparer<ClaseEntidad>.Default.Equals(obj, default(ClaseEntidad)))
    {
        stop = true;
    }
    else
    {
        BDenMemoria.Add(obj);
        i++;
    }
}
while (!stop);
```

Answer (score -1):

Pensaría que basta con volverla pública y agregar una instancia de tu clase en la clase donde la queres utilizar. Por ejemplo:

```
GenDAO ejemplo = new GENDAO();
```

Y luego accediendo a la propiedad usando:

```
var lista = ejemplo.BDenMemoria;
```

Las variables privadas se llaman así porque pertenecen a esa clase en específico y no debería de ser posible acceder a ellas desde afuera.

Espero te sirva, saludos!

Comment: Gracias! pero en teoría tengo que dejar esa clase tal y como está, sin modificación alguna

Comment: pues mira, así como esta es bien dificil, la única manera que se me ocurren en la que podrías acceder a esa variable es utilizando las propiedades get y set como lo describe aquí: (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-properties). Mira la parte que dice: "The set Accessor".

Answer (score -1):

Creo que la solución más sencilla es usando [`Reflection`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.reflection?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DES-ES%26k%3Dk(System.Reflection);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8), ya que usando la clase [`FieldInfo`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.reflection.fieldinfo?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DES-ES%26k%3Dk(System.Reflection.FieldInfo);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8), los [`BindingFlags`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.reflection.bindingflags?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DES-ES%26k%3Dk(System.Reflection.BindingFlags);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8) correctos y su método [`GetValue`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.reflection.fieldinfo.getvalue?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DES-ES%26k%3Dk(System.Reflection.FieldInfo.GetValue);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8) nos bastaría para obtener la referencia a un campo [`private`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/private?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DES-ES%26k%3Dk(private_CSharpKeyword)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%3Dv4.6.1)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue) [`static`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DES-ES%26k%3Dk(static_CSharpKeyword)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%3Dv4.6.1)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue)

Por ejemplo..

```
//Obtengo el tipo de la clase estática..
Type type = typeof(GenDAO<TuEntidad>);
//Obtengo el objeto FieldInfo pasando el nombre del campo que pretendo obtener y los BindingFlags correspondientes.
FieldInfo info = type.GetField("BDenMemoria", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
//Por último con GetValue obtengo la referncia a la lista que buscamos..
object value = info?.GetValue(null);
//value tendrá adentro la lista BDenMemoria
```